# Beta function from renormalized coupling

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, renormalization, conformal-field-theory

While trying to derive a specific beta function for a CFT a stumbled upon the following. I have some bare coupling $g_b$ and introduce a renormalized coupling $g$ as
$$g_b=\mu^\epsilon(g+\frac{zg^2}{\epsilon}+...)$$
I know the beta function $\beta(g)$ should then be
$$\beta(g)=-\epsilon g+zg^2+...$$
But when trying to derive it I arrive at
$$\beta(g)=\frac{-\epsilon g-zg^2}{1+\frac{2gz}{\epsilon}}+...$$
Firstly, the relative sign between the two terms in the beta function is wrong, and secondly, I get that extra factor diving the whole right hand side. I arrived at this result by taking $\frac{dg_b}{d\mu}=0$. If anyone could point out what I am doing wrong or if I have any conceptual errors, it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The reference I am following is this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.01960 section 4, the derivation starting with formula 4.1 and ending in formula 4.11. There they also calculate the factor $z$.

Edit 2: As pointed out in the comments by Cosmas Zachos what I was missing was just expanding the final result to order $\mathcal{O}(g^2)$. Doing so gives
$$\beta(g)=-(\epsilon g +zg^2+\ldots)(1-\frac{2gz}{\epsilon}+\frac{4g^2z^2}{\epsilon^2}+\ldots)\approx -\epsilon g+zg^2$$

Comment: Did you expand your expression to $O(g^2)$ in *g* ? What did you find? How?