# Beta function of CFT perturbed by several operators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, renormalization, conformal-field-theory

As the title says, I am trying to derive the $\beta$ function of a CFT whose action is perturbed by several operators. The main refference I am following is https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.01960 starting in Formula 4.1 (see also a previous question of mine [Beta function from renormalized coupling](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/769250/beta-function-from-renormalized-coupling)).  In that paper the action is perturbed by only one operator, but now I am interested in a case with several ones. In order to do this I tried the following ansatz for the bare coupling to take into account all possible pairings between the couplings associated to all the operators

$$g^b_i=\mu^{\epsilon_i}(-\epsilon_ig_i+\sum_{j,k}\frac{z_{ijk}}{\epsilon_i}g_jg_k+\ldots)$$

If I try to obtain the $\beta$ like in the case of only one operator I obtain an expression for $\beta_i$ in terms of $\beta_j,\beta_k$ and do not see a way of decoupling the equations. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: In general you will get a set of $\beta$ functions where different couplings are mixed up. The usual strategy is then to first identify any fixed point, and for each fixed point, you can expand the RG equations around it to linear order and then decouple them.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am ok with the different couplings being mixed, in fact I expect a result where the beta function of one couplings depends on all the coupling pairings. What bothers me is that for example the function $\beta_i$ will have terms like $g_j\beta_k$